# Run multiple Jenkins job concurrently based on parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

So I have 3 Appium/Selenium Junit classes, each for a different platform (iOS, Android, web). I'd like to create 3 Jenkins jobs and then run some or all of them in parallel based on parameters that I'll input somehow (file, command, etc.).

Example: I want to run the iOS and Android tests with specific devices (UDIDs). So I'd somehow input this information (which jobs to run and with which parameters=devices), and the 2 jobs will run concurrently with this input.

I'm a Jenkins beginner, and I have tried searching and found many Jenkins plugins that seem like they can help (i.e. Parameterized Trigger Plugin), but I didn't understand how to use these correctly (how to configure the jobs correctly with these plugins). Any help would be appreciated (as "dumbed-down" as possible...)

Answer (score 0):

So it's like this. You can run tests on Jenkins in parallel or in multiple builds. I'm using maven, multiple Jenkins nodes, selenium-grid and bunch of other tools. You can call single maven command so it can run parallel tests at once, for eg. only mobile (Android/iOS), and web in separate build to run tests in parallel run for multiple browsers eg. (Chrome & Firefox...).

There is a several ways to achieve this, but there is lot o preparation and setup:

1. via java/testNg (xml test-suites),
2. set up selenium-grid for multiple instances, 
   Here is great starter article for this: https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-parallel-tests-grid-testng/ 
   https://learn.techbeacon.com/units/how-use-testng-parallel-test-execution
3. (if using for mobile testing) setup Appium to run several instances, here is also nice article to start with: https://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/parallel-tests/
4. have multiple Jenkins nodes, here is something about that, read entire article: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

But main question was about Jenkins, You can achieve this by creating simple Maven build, create Your job, connect it with Your code on git, enter maven command to call Your code, and You should be set to go, again one more article: https://developers.perfectomobile.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21435209.

Good parallelism is hard to achieve, but when You do its is going to make You worth all time invested.

Hope It will help You!

Comment: Thanks, but I must run 3 parallel Jenkins jobs (the parallel work cannot be done by using TestNG or threads for example). I simply need 3 separate Jenkins jobs that will run concurrently (in the code I can check what job it is and run the correct code accordingly). I know it's easier running one Jenkins job and then having the code do the parallel work with TestNG / threads / etc., but I need to run 3 separate Jenkins jobs in parallel.

Comment: open several nodes in Jenkins

Comment: There is a solution You might try: the Multi-Job plugin for Jenkins